# Search git history and group by author

Tags: git

Let say I want to count how many `if`statements have been commited and then group them by author, how would I do that?

Example of what I want to do:

```
git count-by-author "if ("

 245 Author A
 199 Author B
  20 Author C
```

I'm mainly interested in number of `if`s introduced, and not modified `if` statements, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pure git solution, but you can use following bash script to get such stats:

```
for sha in $(git log --format=%H); do
  author="$(git show --format=%an $sha | head -n1)"

  removed_if_statements=$(git show $sha | grep -E '^\-(.* )?if \(' | wc -l)
  added_if_statements=$(git show $sha | grep -E '^\+(.* )?if \(' | wc -l)

  delta=$(( $added_if_statements - $removed_if_statements ))

  if [ $delta -gt 0 ]; then
    for x in $(seq 1 $delta); do
      echo $author
    done
  fi
done | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg
```

Comment: Nice! just needed to add -g to the final `sort` to get things sorted correctly (8 was sorted before 1100 for example)

Comment: also, this line seems to require zsh ` for x in {1..$delta}; do`

Comment: Apparently `{1..5}` works in bash, but `var=5; {1..$var}` works only in zsh. I have not been aware of that. I've updated answer again.